# Big O complexity to merge two lists

Tags: algorithm, merge, time-complexity, singly-linked-list

**Given 2 singly linked lists already sorted, merge the lists.**

Example:
list1:  1 2 3 5 7
list2:  0 4 6 7 10
--->    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 10

Despite from the fact that the solution is quite simple and there are several different implementations of the problem with or without using recursion (like this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/  see Method 3),

**I was wondering what would be the O big complexity of this implementation:**

1. If one of the lists is empty just return the other
2. Otherwise insert each node of the second list into the first one using the sortedInsert function which basically scan the list until the right position is found. Because the 2 lists are both already sorted there's no need to compare each time the node with all the nodes in the first list, I can start the comparison from the last added node.

ex: continuing with the previous example if 4 has been already added I can safely start the next comparison from 4:
list1:  0 1 2 3 **4** 5 7
list2:  6 7 10
now compare 6 with 4 instead with 1 2 3 4....

**If I would compare one element with all the elements in the first list it would be O(m*n) with m=#list2 and n=#list1, but considering this "optimisation" what is the complexity?**

Implementation:

```
// Insert a new node in a sorted list
int sortedInsert(struct ListNode **head, struct ListNode* newNode) {
    int headUpdated = 0;
    struct ListNode *current;

    // The list is empty or the new element has to be added as first element
    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->data >= newNode->data) {
        newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode;
        headUpdated = 1;
    }
    else {
        // Locate the node before the point of insertion
        current = *head;
        while (current->next != NULL && current->next->data < newNode->data)
            current = current->next;

        newNode->next = current->next;
        current->next = newNode;
    }

    return headUpdated;
}


struct ListNode *mergeLists(struct ListNode *head1, struct ListNode *head2) {
    if (head1 == NULL)
        return head2;

    if (head2 == NULL)
        return head1;

    // Store the node in the first list where to start the comparisons
    struct ListNode *first = head1;

    while (head2) {
        struct ListNode *head2Next = head2->next;

        printf("Adding %d starting comparison from %d\n", head2->data, first->data);
        if (sortedInsert(&first, head2))
            head1 = first;

        first = head2;
        head2 = head2Next;
    }

    return head1;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 No, each comparison is followed by either an insertion or a `current = current->next`. There are `n` insertions, and at most `m + n - 1` advancements.

Comment: If you sit down and work out the sequence of operations, you'll see that your version is equivalent to the standard list merge, just written differently.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, there are two factors, right. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the merge algorithm you have here is **`O(m + n)`**, not `O(m * n)`.

Since you have a pointer to the last inserted node, and start looking for the place to insert the next node from that on, the total number of

```
current = current->next
```

operations in `sortedInsert` is at most `m + n - 1` (length of result minus one). The number of insert operations (relinking the `next` pointers) is `n` (length of the second list). For each comparison

```
current->next->data < newNode->data
```

the next operation is either an insertion or a `current = current->next`, so the number of comparisons is at most

```
m + 2*n - 1
```

Let us say that the resulting list starts with `m_0` elements from the first list, then `n_1` elements from the second, then `m_1` from the first, `n_2` from the second, ..., `n_r` from the second, then finally `m_r` from the first. `m_0` and `m_r` may be 0, all other numbers are strictly positive.

The first element of the `n_1` block is compared to each element of the `m_0` block and the first element of the `m_1` block. All other elements of that block are compared to their predecessor in the second list, and the first element of the `m_1` block [unless `r = 1` and `m_1 = 0`, in which case there are fewer comparisons].

That makes `m_0 + 1 + (n_1 - 1)*2 = m_0 + 2*n_1 - 1` comparisons (or fewer).

For the later `n_k` blocks, the first element is compared to the last element of the `n_(k-1)` block, all elements of the `m_(k-1)` block, and the first element of the `m_k` block [if that exists]. The further elements of the block are all compared to their predecessor in list 2, and the first element of the `m_k` block [if that exists], that makes

```
 1 + m_(k-1) + 1 + (n_k - 1)*2 = m_(k-1) + 2*n_k
```

comparisons (or fewer). Since all comparisons involve at least one element of the second list, the total number of comparisons is at most

```
m_0 + 2*n_1 - 1 + m_1 + 2*n_2 + m_2 + 2*n_3 + ... + m_(r-1) + 2*n_r <= m + 2*n - 1.
```

We can slightly improve it by intialising

```
    struct ListNode *first = head1;
```

and removing the

```
    if (!first)
        first = head1;
```

test from the loop.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your formal demonstration of the O(m + n). Happy to see that my implementation works better than I was thinking! I will update my accepted answer shortly.