# Merge two linked lists Order

Tags: list, merge

I have two sorted linked lists and need to merge them.

l1 = [a] -> [b] -> [c]

l2 = [b] -> [f]

l1plus2 = [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [f]

What order would this be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O complexity to merge two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495034/big-o-complexity-to-merge-two-lists)

Comment: Please edit your post to explain what "order" do you mean. Answer so far assumes "time complexity"... but it is very unclear if matches you goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, ascending order. :) Kidding.

If you mean "order of magnitude", the following solution will be O(m+n) or O(max(m,n)) where m is l1.length and n is l2.length.

Algorithm: Keep a pointer to each linked list, step through both, and add the lesser of the two elements. If the elements are the same, add it once and step both pointers.